# To have the shit beaten out of

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

How does one translate into French "I had the shit beaten out of me"?

I am writing, in French, a short biography of the Australian painter Ben Quilty. He uses these words to describe his time at school: "I had the shit flogged out of me by Brother Luke", a key to his strength of feeling for the underdog.

Comment: We need more context. Is this utterance related to a specific event or not?

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez♦ Yes. It never (as far as I can imagine) could refer to anything but an event, whether single or repeated.

Comment: If you don't know anything about it, you can only expect a best guess translation then.

Comment: It's a common expression in English. It means to be beaten very severely, but expressed in a vulgar way. The specific context (for what it's worth) of the question, as stated, is that Quilty had been the victim of physical abuse by a Catholic cleric. But you don't need to know that to understand the meaning of "had the shit flogged out of me".

Comment: Granted, one might not need to know "The specific context (for what it's worth)" to understand the exact quote at issue, but knowing the context does tempt me to want to (playfully/cynically) expand the original quote to "had the HOLY shit flogged out of me," or even to change it to "had the DEVIL flogged out of me"!

Comment: @Papa Poule: The meaning of “hair” is perfectly clear to me, yet I need context in order to translate it. Without context expect funny and possibly harmful mistranslations.

Comment: In the case of the one with _flogged_ does that mean that a stick or whip was used or just generally beaten like with the shit beaten out of? Thanks!

Comment: @nonobstant fascisme : In olden times, the word "flogged" implied the use of a whip. These days, and particularly in Australia, "flogged" simply means "beaten hard", with or without an instrument. Since Quilty is talking about his Catholic school, a stick or cane is most likely to have been used.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of an abuse, for the description of a one time event,

- you could use:

  > Brother Luke m'a foutu une (putain de) raclée.

  Note that *foutu* is already vulgar language, probably as much as *shit* is, but you can add *putain de* if you'd like to insist on that aspect.
- or at the expense of a significant language register mismatch you could use:

  > Il ne m'a pas raté.

  It probably fits better if it's used as some kind of a “punchline” (pun not intended).

In the case of a general description of repeated events, the first one can be modified slightly like so:

> Il me mettait des putains de raclées.

Note that I chose to discard “Il me foutait” because it lacks solemnity.

Just in case, any other familiar expression I thought of before knowing the context would forbid sexual violence connotations (if there was any) and most of them wouldn't be quite suited to describe “physical abuse” by a person in charge in any case anyway. I guess there are more but they didn't come to mind yet.

Comment: The most objectionable problem in those translations is the total ignorance of the whip and that is a drawback not to neglect in the light of an always present necessity of preserving as much as possible factualness and consistency in the picture painted to the reader. Isn't it preferable to sacrifice vulgarity to the whip?

Comment: @LPH: the whip is the least of the OP's many problems.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: It was in fact a frequent occurrence, but can you explain further why you wouldn't use "il me foutait"?

Comment: “Il me foutait” sounds more like something you'd say casually.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: Quilty is an Australian, and like most Australians, speaks very informally even in interviews, like the one in which he spoke those words.

Comment: It isn't a matter of formality as the sentence is very clearly informal. It's a matter of putting weight into words. Oh, and… should you think of rendering the Australian vernacular into French, you'd be asking for too much :-)

Comment: To justify the rollback, with the final choice to the original author: [putain](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/putain) in the TLFi → *«Il a une de ces putains de canadienne à me faire baver»*, Jean GIONO — *«Je l'ai payée à la fin! Tout payé! Sous par sous! De la garcerie de ma putaine existence!»*, CÉLINE

Comment: @Montée de lait: j'avoue que je ne me suis jamais posé la question. L'orthographe c'est une question de formalité or dans cette phrase il y en a très peu. Je ne suis en fait pas entièrement contre la correction, car je me rends compte que je ne dirais pas *putaine* au féminin (sauf dans le très rare cas d'un vrai adjectif).

Comment: Moi non plus, probablement jamais *putaine*, mais Céline est Céline, jamais effrayé de risquer un néologisme ou d'opter pour une tournure nouvelle et étrange. Giono, par contre, est plus sobre, et a néanmoins opté pour le pluriel.

Answer (score 2):

« être battu comme plâtre »  is fine for situations such as fist fighting. In the case of flogging one can use "fouetter jusqu'au sang". The register of those expressions is however current. There does not exist, apparently, a phrase that would include the word "merde".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

> *Je me suis pris des putain de branlées par frère Luke.*